# trying to understand a self executing function composed of several arrow functions in a filter()

Tags: javascript

trying to understand:

```
.filter((s => ([, v]) => s.add(v).size <= 3)(new Set))
```

in

```
const object = { B: 3, A: 2, C: 2, D: 1, E: 0, F: 0 },
result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)                         // just to be sure
        .filter((s => ([, v]) => s.add(v).size <= 3)(new Set))
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

from this question [Find top 3 values entries in a sorted JavaScript dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295308/find-top-3-values-entries-in-a-sorted-javascript-dictionary/70295414#70295414)

I don't understand the notation in filter, around arrow functions and why there is (new Set) at the end.
I'm not used to arrow functions because I'm a beginner with JavaScript.

Comment: You need to look into Arrow functions, destructuring assignment. `[,v]` means you are picking value from set and ignoring first argument by `[,`. Its similar to `[k,v]` but you do not need `k` so you do not use it

Comment: @Rajesh thks. my problem is not about the destructuring but about (...)(newSet) notation.

Comment: That is IIFE syntax but for more clarity, we will need more context/ code

Comment: @Rajesh yes it is from this post Nina Scholz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295308/find-top-3-values-entries-in-a-sorted-javascript-dictionary/70295414#70295414

Comment: That is IIFE syntax. This `([, v]) => s.add(v).size <= 3)(new Set)` will be executed and `s` will be passed to `new Set` And output will be returned as filter's callback's body

Comment: Ok thks I will try to figure this out.
why so hatred people there? 4 dislikes to my question in few seconds. I'm french, and I had not idea about keywords around this question. damn

Comment: The votes are because your question is poorly formed. You have not done research and/ or not projected properly. SO is to help fellow devs with their problems but not a tutoring class or get code for free site. So your question should look like a PROBLEM statement

Comment: yes I'm searching from yesterday. how can you formulate something you have never hear of? there it's ()() in a filter that I don't understand. seriously I have still no idea how to formulate this differently but really thks for your answer anyway

Comment: I trust you but go back to your first edit. Does it look like a PROBLEM statement? Does it tell what you are confused/ unaware of? I understand you are a bit frustrated with daily work stuff but so are others. So please be clear

Comment: You can refer this for simplicity: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1m7g8Lr/)**

Answer (score 0):

At first I didn't understand this type of notation clearly

`const demo = a => b => b + a`

this is a function returning another function

then the ([, v]) was pretty clear, a destructuring assignment to work on the value

but I was still confused by the general structure of (s => ([, v]) => s.add(v).size <= 3)(new Set) like (...)(new Set)
this is an Immediately Invoked Function (IIF) like ((a) => 2 * a)(4)
Now I understand, with a simpler function

so a more explicit code would have been

```
const object = { B: 3, A: 2, C: 2, D: 1, E: 0, F: 0 }
const s = new Set()
const result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object
      .entries(object)
      .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)
      .filter(([, v]) => s.add(v).size <= 3)
);

console.log(result);
```

I was trying to understand each element, without having a general vision. Logical for a beginner.

BTW, the example given is not wonderful, it would have been better to do a simple slice on the three first values than a filter.

Comment: One liners and nested arrow functions do not really increase readability and maintainability. So I can relate to your issue.

Comment: @Lain Agreed. The goal in this answer is to decode and understand this strange notation. It happens to see such code on GitHub. A moderator thought it was beautiful. But on a general level, you are right. And I lost reputation points asking. In a bad way certainly, being lost.